# Unix Command to get file path without basename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have following file in unix directory

```
/home/files/myfiles/good.txt
```

I need to extract the file path alone

**Expected output** : `/home/files/myfiles`

**Note**: I can not use cut operations as the file path is dynamic. I am getting the filename and filepath as single user input to the shell script

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
$ dirname /home/files/myfiles/good.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Without spawning another process, you can use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```
file=/home/files/myfiles/good.txt
echo "${file%/*}"
/home/files/myfiles
```

Answer (score 1):

Should do the job:

```
echo /home/files/myfiles/good.txt | sed s,/*[^/]*$,,
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, `cut` CAN do it dynamically with a little help of `rev`

```
$ echo "/home/files/myfiles/good.txt" | rev | cut -d/ -f2- | rev
/home/files/myfiles

$ echo "/home/files/myfiles/yourfiles/good.txt" | rev | cut -d/ -f2- | rev
/home/files/myfiles/yourfiles
```